# My sqlite3 file won't get copied after my qt-based project gets deployed (android)

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I'm making a project using Qt and I need to deploy it for Android. When I try to open my sqlite3 file inside it, it won't open because it seems it isn't copied on deployment/building.

This is my pro file.

```
QT += quick sql
QT += quickcontrols2
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    database.cpp \
    listmodel.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    database.h \
    listmodel.h

CONFIG += qzxing_qml
CONFIG += qzxing_multimedia

include(qzxing/src/QZXing.pri)


DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android

android
{
my_files.path = /assets
my_files.files = $$PWD/sqlitedb/*
INSTALLS += my_files
}
```

If I look inside phone's filesystem, my sqlite3 file is not present.

```
130|generic_x86:/data/user/0 # find / -iname "*.sqlite3" 2>/dev/null
1|generic_x86:/data/user/0 #
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. File is placed inside your apk file - check it, assets directory should contain all files you wanted. Accessing them on the device is trivial. You have to open it as a resource files, but instead of `qrc:///dir/file` `assets:/db.sqlite`. You can open it, but file will be read only. However it can always be copied to one of the writable directories(remember that assets directory is read only as it is inside your apk file!):
`QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` or `QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation`

```
QString localStorage = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
if(QFile::copy("assets:/db.sqlite", localStorage + "/db.sqlite"))
   qDebug() <<"File copied to " << localStorage << endl;
```

Comment: I'm already making this:
 https://pastebin.com/ZGaaaxyJ
My program is telling me the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you check contents of your apk file?
In my case it is working OK: https://pastebin.com/Tu5qCgME
https://i.imgur.com/Zlnvxyu.png

Comment: @sudo_woodo: there is a logic problem with your code. You ask if the database file exists *before* copying it from your assets. So the file never exists, and it never gets copied either.

Comment: @bialy: I was not replying to you.

Comment: @Pedro I figured that out a little bit too late :) Sorry for that.